# PostgreSQL maunally inserted record vs Spring JPA Save with sequence

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.6

Here is my entity and table structure as below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "user_data_seq")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "FName")
private String fname; 
@Column(name = "LName")
Private String lname;

CREATE TABLE user
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_data_seq'::regclass),
    fname character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,,
    lname character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_fname_unique UNIQUE (fname)
}
```

I have made one manual entry in USER through pgAdmin, its inserted with the latest sequence value.

```
INSERT INTO user(fname, lname) VALUES('AAA', 'BBB');
```

Now application is using and trying to update the LName for the existing record. But looks like JPA is considering this as new entry and trying re-insert, due to that unique constraint violation error is occurring.

```
public User updateLName(final User user) {
    User userToUpdate = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
    userToUpdate.setLName("CCC");
    userToUpdate = userRepository.save(userToUpdate);
    return userToUpdate;
  }
```

The below code (if condition) from [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) JPA, is still returning as true and make the record to insert as NEW :

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository
@Transactional
  public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
      this.em.persist(entity);
      return entity;
    } else {
      return this.em.merge(entity);
    }
  }
```

But this wont be a problem for the records inserted through application already and again able to update.

Comment: how do you update the record by codes ?

Comment: In the code, user object is found based on FName. In this case the complete object is found by FName='AAA' and retrieved from the database. Then before before repository.save(user) called, it is retrieved by id again and modified the LName.

Answer (score 0):

The identity of entities is defined by their primary keys. So you have to specify which data you want to update. To update existing using `save()` method you can fetch the existing data by id.

```
User userToUpdate = userRepository.getOne(id);
```

The update its data

```
userToUpdate.setFname(userDto.getFName());
```

And finally, call the save method it update the data in database

```
userRepository.save(userToUpdate);
```

Comment: Yes in the similar fashion, the data has retrieved by id 1st and assigned to userToUpdate object, modified and sent to userRepository.save(userToUpdate). It's a same error.

Comment: @Mahi Can you show us the code you tried in question. It's needed to understand you saving object detached or not

Comment: Here is my small code : public User updateLName(final User user) {
    User userToUpdate = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
    userToUpdate.setLName("CCC");
    userToUpdate = userRepository.save(userToUpdate);
    return userToUpdate;
  }

Comment: @Mahi please attached in question, in comment it's unreadable

Comment: sorry attached now

Comment: @Mahi I don't think there is any problem,  maybe problem is somewhere else, try to post full code used for request , like controllers service repository. I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: ah, my mistake, the table was having a version column, and it was inserted as null that's where it was conserding as NEW.